# Recursively apply -arch option to all dependencies of a Xcode project

Tags: xcode, macos, xcodebuild, xcode-build-settings

I have a script that build a list of Xcode projects using xcodebuild command line tool. After introduction of universal builds we introduced standard arch's in our xcconfig files and build settings of Xcode projects. Now I want to add an option to build only given arch's. For this I added option -arch . This works well for projects that I build using the list. Problem happens when the system tries to build dependent projects internally and since there the arch is set to universal it fails to build since its dependencies are now either intel only of arm64 only. Is there some argument I can give to xcodebuild to apply -arch option to all its dependencies as well.